# Regex for one string or a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

i am trying to write a regent for a line in this format:

> Integer;characters etc;decimal number;decimal number;decimal
>   number;characters etc

For example:

> 989898;ABCD - eft;9809.98078;9878.876;8768.654;ABCD

For this, I have writen this which is working fine :

```
/[0-9]*;(.)*;[0-9\.]*;[0-9\.]*;[0-9\.]*;(.)/gi
```

Now, this problem is, there can be N.A. in the place of decimal number for which I am unable to get the refer right.

Comment: `there can be N.A. in the place of decimal number` , post an example.

Comment: `([0-9\.]+)|(N\.A\.)` would be fine, but you may want to refactor some of this to use `\d` and also you're allowing empty values for numbers which may not be what you want. And `(.)` will *not* match `ABCD`

Comment: What do you want to happen if you find NA in your input versus the expected numeric? In other words, do you want the NA to be filtered, do you want to throw an error, do you want that specific instance of data to be disregarded, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) for this. Also, you can improve your regex a bit - for example `[^;]*`  is more specific than `.*`, you can avoid repetition, and you don't need to escape the dot inside a character class:

```
/[0-9]*;[^;]*;(?:N\.A\.;|[0-9.]*;){3}.*/gi
```